# taking an array of dates and correlating to an array from a database to make a schedule

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am in the middle of making a scheduling program that will be displayed on a bigger touchscreen TV.  I have an array call date[] that just contains the date of every friday for the year since our company refers to weeks by their fridays, and that's how it is in the database I'm pulling from. I'm using moment.js:

```
  var date = [];
        var newDate;


        for (var x = 0; x < 52; x++) {

            newDate = moment().startOf('year').day('friday').add(x, "weeks").add(when, "years");
            newDate = moment(newDate).format('MM-DD-YYYY');
            date.push(newDate);
```

then I have three columns of a local database being pulled out and being pushed into a multidimensional array in php

```
 foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
        array_push($jobNo, $row['JobNumber']);
        array_push($jobState, $row['JobState']);
        $dform = new DateTime($row['WeekDate']);
        $dform = $dform->format('m-d-y');
        array_push($jobDate, strval($dform));
    }
```

and then I'm transferring it into a javascript array:

```
<?php $data = getData(); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var data = <?php json_encode(print_r($data)); ?> ;
</script>
```

getData() is the php function I'm using to pull the data from the database.
I have a grid of draggable squares with each of the dates of the fridays on them and I'm dragging them to a drop panel and saving the date in a selection[] array.

But, now I'm about to just take the dates selected and use a table view on another page where I will be showing the data of just the selected dates.  Is there anyway for me to maybe take it another step deeper and relate the date array to the data array? or is it possible to sort the data array by the date and just keep everything else with the job number and state?

I'm fairly new to making something this in depth so any help is welcome.  Thank you very much in advance.

**EDIT:**  What I want to be able to be able to use the date to call all the job numbers and job states that might be connected to that date.

pretty much like

```
foreach(date[] as day){
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
         if (date == data[1][i]) 
             //but right here I'm not sure where to go or what to do
             //I would like to just be able to call data[05-19-17] and         
             //use that to list the job numbers and job states related to 
             // that date.  
 }
}
```

Comment: Could you give some sample output, as the PHP is unneccessary for your question...

Comment: if both arrays contain a relation one on one of their elements, all you need is to know the "index" or position of the selected dates to be able to pull the data from the other array...

Comment: Each index of the data array contains a date of a friday which is MM-DD-YY format, it contains a job number which is about 5 to 6 numbers and then a job state which is a string with no spaces in it. so   var data = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 09-08-17
            [1] => 62154
            [2] => Approved ) and in the date array the dates are in order but in the other array they are not in the correct order and there are more than one jobs on each day.